# When can we use Oracle external tables

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I have read many posts compaing External table with sqlloader and the main advantage is optimizing the select query with many options available in SQL for the external table. But i am finding it difficult to do selects on large files(1.5 GB). Just for a select count(*) itself it takes minutes to perform.

My plan is to generate a report based on this data by doing a number of select statements from this data. I wonder if this is a better idea compared to loading the data to an internal table.

I assume the ideal use of External table would be to do SELECT on the file to perform cleanup and Load to an internal table more efficiently. It is not meant to use the file as a table for a longer duration(Especially for large files). Please correct if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to execute multiple select on data from big file it is much better to load it to some internal staging table (either by SQLoader or by external table and insert as select) and then perform queries. 
You should probably consider creating some indexes on table to speed up your queries.